# Overlapping Markers with AngularGM directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I have two markers that are very close to each other. When the map is zoomed out they overlap.

Problem: There is a marker event that changes the icon of one of the markers but it won't show for the marker that is behind. Is there a way to bring the marker to the front? Perhaps using CSS or some event with angularGM API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually obtain and modify a marker's `z-index` using the `getZIndex()` and `setZIndex()` marker methods.

Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker

Comment: The only problem is I don't have access to getZIndex() marker method from the angularGM marker. Or I am unaware how to retrieve the correct marker object.

Comment: According to the documentation for `angularGM` - the `google.maps.Marker` object is passed as the second argument to any marker event callback function. That is the object that has the `getZIndex()` and `setZIndex()` methods.